# Unix Shell Script: While loop

Tags: shell, unix, while-loop

I want to print the numbers in the following pattern using WHILE loop.

```
0
01
012
0123
.....
......
0123456789
```

## My Try:

```
#!/bin/sh

a=0
b=0 

while [ $a -le 10 ]
do  
        while [ $b -le $a ]
        do
                echo -n "$b"
                b=`expr $b + 1`
        done
        echo
        a=`expr $a + 1`
done
```

Getting output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: Have you realized that you only print the `b` value which is incremented in each iteration? In other words, have you thought about the algorithm?

Comment: You should use a variable to save the last output (`012`). Then you should append it the value of `b` and print it and increase the counter.

Comment: Is there a specific requirement to use a `while` loop? What shell are you using? `expr` is a non-standard, old-fashioned way of doing arithmetic in the shell.

Comment: @MAK, as you accepted the Ben's answer as a solution, can I assume the shell you are using is `bash`, not any other `UNIX shell` as you have tagged this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you simply append the latest count to the line output, simply do so as text.

```
#!/bin/bash

a=0
out=''

while [ $a -lt 10 ]
do
    out=$out$a
    echo $out
    a=`expr $a + 1`
done
```

Also, `le` is less or equal, so you end up with 10. Use `lt 10` or `le 9`.

Comment: Why not use `a=$(( a + 1 ))` instead of `expr`? It should work in any POSIX-compliant that isn't too old.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `bash`shell, you can take advantage of sequence expressions of the form **`{x..y}`** and use the special parameter **`$_`** which usually expands to the last argument to the previous command.

```
#/bin/bash
i=
for i in {0..9}
do
     echo "$_$i"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=0                                                                           
b=1                                                                                             
while [ $a -lt 10 ]                                                                         
do                                                                                                                                                               
    a=0                                                                                                                                                      
    while [ $a -lt $b ]                                                                                                                                      
    do                                                                                                                                                       
    echo -n $a                                                                                                                                               
    a=`expr $a + 1 `                                                                                                                                         
done                                                                                                                                                     

echo                                                                                                                                                             

b=`expr $b + 1`                                                                                                                                                  

done
```